My Coinbase Wallet Seedphrase is compromised
An address has taken all my Ether. My problem is that i linked my wallet with a few presale crypto. How do i go about it? How do i link a new wallet with the connected presale cryptos?

Is probably going to depend on the distribution methods of each crypto.
If the amount of crypto has a valuation of $1000 or greater and is on Ethereum (potentially Solana), then you can contact Flashbots protect rescue service, and their whitehats can set up rescues for the days the tokens launch and attempt to front run the scammer in withdrawing.
You can find the flashbots protect team on their discord.

link from the website:


https://discord.com/invite/7hvTycdNcK





https://www.flashbots.net/




https://docs.flashbots.net/flashbots-auction/other-resources



Join the channel: #⛑whitehat-token-rescue-service
Verify the links and information I am giving you, don't blindly trust anyone who says they can help you recover funds

Are these guys legit?

Yes they are well funded well respected group in the space with a dedicated rescue team, performing rescues around the clock.

Thanks for your advice man. However none of the whitehats have taken my case yet. Lets hope for the best. 12th april is the date when my staked tokens can be claimed.

So you have filled in the form and are waiting, can message someone with the serv.eth role in #general and just confirm they have received it and your user name is in the list. But yes it is not guaranteed that someone will be available to take the case. Have fingers crossed for you.

Thanks man, a whitehat rescued my tokens. Thanks again for introducing me to this awesome community of great people. God bless. The crypto market took a dive thou. :-)

Let's go, much love. Yea market is down, don't get shaken out, see you on the other side ; )
